# upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 from Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: upgrade

I have been using Ubuntu 13.04 and want to upgrade to 13.10. Last time when I did many of my applications stopped working like Evance and I had to format my hard drive. Can anybody help me to understand what is more appropriate upgrading or fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to 14.04 because 13.10.support will end tomorrow(after 9 Months of support).

Comment: But reviews regarding 14.04 are not better than 13.10.

Comment: Even if there are no major improvements you want in 14.04 you still should choose it to get the latest updates. I see no drawback in choosing 14.04 over 13.10. Alternatively you could choose 12.04 which, as a LTS, is still supported to.